# Public members in static class c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to understand static classes in c# . Thing i want to do is that i want to create a static configuration class . In which i am going to define multiple public member which can be accessible from outside like `ConnectionString` and other application related configuration . How to do this ?

```
public static class config {
    public static string con {get; set;}
    public static bool IsProduction {get; set;}
    public static string FileLogPath {get; set;}
}
```

this is what i am doing now do i need to define all variable's values in constructor or not ?

Comment: you have a class in place, where is the code that sets the values for this class, you should place that code in the application start up so that you can access it through out the application

Comment: There is not so much code only need to fetch values from web.config and assign into variables .

Comment: I know i can directly get values from webconfig but i made a seperate project for config and add a reference into website of that project . that's why i am doing like this way

Comment: You can either use a static Constructor `static config() {...}` or - which I'd recommend in that cases - use the singleton-pattern and make the class non static. OR use the Settings file provided by the c# projects ins VS.

Comment: @TGlatzer can you explain me your comment as answer

Comment: Someone was faster - and the answer looks good.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually better handled via singleton pattern. Exceptions in static constructor are nightmare + when you use singleton pattern your object is always in consistent state and initialization is performed on demand for the first call of `Config.Instance`.

```
public class Config {
  private static Config s_Config;

  public static Config Instance {
    get {
      if (s_Config == null)
      {
        // fetch members
        string con = "";
        bool isProduction = false;
        string fileLogPath = "";
        s_Config = new Config(con, isProduction, fileLogPath);
      }
      return s_Config;
    }
  }

  private Config(string con, bool isProduction, string fileLogPath)
  {
    Con = con; 
    IsProduction = isProduction;
    FileLogPath = fileLogPath;
  }

  public string Con { get; private set; }
  public bool IsProduction { get; private set; }
  public string FileLogPath { get; private set; }
}
```

As noted by @khlr - this is simple example and initialization part of singleton is not thread safe. If thread safety is an issue refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: can you explain sir ?

Comment: @Ancient if you _really_ wanna use a singleton for that purpose than better to it "better" using [this sample form the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with double check locking. And additionally [keep this in mind](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).